# In MVC5, how to ensure that the user contained in a cookie still exists or the password has no changed from last login?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In ASP.NET MVC5 projects and when using Individual User Accounts, OWIN uses a cookie to save the authentication related information. By default the cookie is set to expire when browser session ends or to 14 days from the last log in, when the user select the "Remember Me" option.

So, as Microsoft configures the MVC5 project template, by default, if the cookie is present in the browser, and it is not expired, the user will be "logged in" automatically and without authenticating the user in the business layer. With the default configuration: 14 days and sliding expiration, a user that choose the "remember me" and use the site at least once each 14 days will stay always logged in.

So with this configuration, there can be a security problem when we remove an existing user account or we change the password. The user will be able to enter to the site and he won't be asked for a new user/password.

I have modified the configuration in Startup.Auth.cs file to minimize the problem disabling the sliding expiration and reducing the expiration time span, but this do not solve the problem:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.use.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LoginAlert"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0),
            SlidingExpiration = false              
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any standard or recommended way in MVC5/OWIN to ensure that the user account still exists, the roles have no changed or the password has no changed from last login in that browser? Also, I would like to minimize the number of times we go to the database.

Answer (score 1):

In the next version there will be something called the SecurityStampValidator which is used in conjunction with the CookieAuthenticationProvider to protect against this.

Comment: Will someone provide a pointer to the current way to handle this situation? (since I see "next version")

Answer (score 0):

Until there is something built in to handle this, can't you just add logic somewhere in the entry point of the application that checks if the user exists and sign them out if they were deleted? And for the password changed case, add another column to the database that stores a unique key, and add the same key to the claims stored in the cookie, and when a password is changed you change the unique key in the database. Every time the user goes to your site, you compare the key stored in the cookie with the one in the db, and sign the user out if they don't match.